# Sharepont hosted app in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

SharePoint hosted app and provider hosted app difference in SP 2013.

I need detailed explanation and with live examples , when to use both apps in share point 2013.

Answer (score 0):

In short:

**SharePoint hosted app**

A SharePoint hosted app consists of

- Custom Lists
- Custom Pages
- Custom Columns
- Pure Javascript

That means, when you can built up you app on pure Javascript and SharePoint artefact like lists and pages, then you can use a SharePoint hosted app. This also can be deployed to SharePoint online.

**Provider hosted app**

You can think of a provider hosted app like a custom asp.net mvc/form web application, with own .aspx pages, codebehing, web service, etc. Everything you can do within a webapp.

There is much infos on the web. I would prefer to read some articles out there. Especially MSDN/TechNet articles on building SP hosted and provider hosted apps. You will get in short an idea based on the provided information and possibilities within those solution types what you can and cannot do.